# Using charAt in System.out.println displays integer?

Tags: java

If I run this simple code, the output I get is an integer value anyone know why?
I'm trying to print first character of the first name and the first five character of the last name concatenated together.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
String firstName, lastName;

System.out.print ("Enter First Name: ");
firstName = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print ("\n");
System.out.print ("Enter Last Name: ");
lastName = scan.nextLine();

System.out.println (firstName.charAt(0)+lastName.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
System.out.println (firstName.charAt(0)+lastName.charAt(0));
```

you end up calling [System.out.println(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28int%29) due to the addition of the character values themselves yielding an integer value.

> I'm trying to print first character of the first name and the first five character of the last name concatenated together.

You could use:

```
System.out.println(firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.substring(0, 5));
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But why does it return an integer?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the best answer (in my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

Primitive `char` is a compatible type with primitive `int` in Java and if you add chars you will get the sum of their ASCII codes.

```
System.out.println (firstName.charAt(0)+""+lastName.charAt(0));
```

Comment: It was downvoted because the answer started very incorrect, cause of downvote, followed by several edits. Way to be first to answer, followed by edits to get to the right answer to get points?

Comment: I wonder who down voted this answer. I prefer this over the other answer. Very objective.

Comment: @Michael, what do you mean "his answer wasn't edited in the first place"? It was edited at least 10 times with in 5 minutes. Too bad SO isn't showing the history of edits, to the advantage of person answering.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
String firstName, lastName;

System.out.print ("Enter First Name: ");
firstName = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print ("\n");
System.out.print ("Enter Last Name: ");
lastName = scan.nextLine();
String s = "" + firstName.charAt(0)+""+lastName.substring(0, 5);
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Java Language Specification:

> If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the operation is string concatenation.
>   Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the + operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18

Since the primitive `char` type is not supported by the `+` operator, the JVM converts the `char` value to a numeric value, which is the ASCII code.

To get the value you want, use String values (e.g. by calling .substring()), or force a conversion to String, as is done in Bobby Dizzle's answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this : 
`System.out.println (firstName.charAt(0)+lastName.charAt(0));`

You basically try to add a `char` with a `char`. And the compiler actually tries to do the addition with the numeric value. So `println` print the result of the addition.

To actually print what you want, could use the `+` operator with a string (using the `subString`) or use `String.Format`.

So you could also write this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%c %s", firstName.charAt(0), lastName.subString(0,5)));
```